# Open Maps draggable circle with adjustable radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, openstreetmap

I used to use google maps for this but their library has given me [CSP 'unsafe-eval' errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608394/csp-unsafe-eval-using-google-maps-api). I want to remain secure so I'm starting to look at Open Maps.

Here's a screencast of the functionality I want to port over to Open Maps - http://screencast.com/t/5f5LeAesRr. On map click I want a circle that is draggable with an adjustable radius. Using leaflet I was able to get a circle to show on the map but it isn't draggable and the radius can't be adjusted by dragging as shown in the GMaps screencast. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and this [Circle Editor plugin](https://github.com/kartena/Leaflet.EditableHandlers)

Here's a small example using dependencies from https://github.com/kartena/Leaflet.EditableHandlers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>maps</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map { width: 481px;height: 300px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin dependecies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/marker-extend.css" />

    <script src="../lib/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.CircleEditor.js" ></script>
    <!-- End plugin dependecies -->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <br>
    <input id="lat" placeholder="lat" type="number"/>
    <input id="lng" placeholder="lng" type="number"/>
    <input id="radius" placeholder="radius" type="number"/>

    <script>

        var map = L.map('map').setView([40, -98.50], 4);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
        }).addTo(map);




        var updateValues = function(circle) {
            console.log(circle._latlng.lat, circle._latlng.lng ,circle._mRadius);
            $('#lat').val(circle._latlng.lat);
            $('#lng').val(circle._latlng.lng);
            $('#radius').val(circle._mRadius);

        }

        // Set only one circle
        var circleSet = false;

        var onMapClick = function(e) {
            if (!circleSet) {
                var circleLocation = new L.LatLng(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng),
                circleOptions = {
                    color: '#0159E5', 
                    fillColor: '#A8C5E4', 
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    extendedIconClass : 'extend-icon'
                };

                var circle = new L.CircleEditor(circleLocation, 786500, circleOptions);
                map.addLayer(circle);
                circleSet = true;
                updateValues(circle);
                circle.on('edit', function(){
                    updateValues(this);
                });
            }
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);

    </script>

    <!-- From https://github.com/kartena/Leaflet.EditableHandlers -->
</body>
</html>
```